# Development environment similar to virtualenv for C++

Tags: c++, virtualenv

I am looking for a tool that lets me switch between different versions of the packages/builds I use for development purpose something similar to `virtualenv` for python. I am using install prefix at the moment but, I was wondering if there is something for C++

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you acquire the dependencies in question, using a package manager like [conan](https://conan.io/) is what comes to mind for C++. It allows to define dependencies of specific versions and manages the acquisition and setup of a build environment with them, including pre-built binaries. Switching toolset is accomplished by specifying a profile file that describes that toolset (see [this example](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html#examples) in conan's documentation).